# Limit rakefile settings to specific enviorment

Tags: heroku, cucumber, rake, asset-pipeline, production-environment

I have a problem, my rake file looks like this:

```
require File.expand_path('../config/application', __FILE__)
require 'cucumber'
require "cucumber/rake/task"

Whois::Application.load_tasks

Cucumber::Rake::Task.new(:features) do |t|
  t.cucumber_opts = "features --format pretty"
end
```

And the main reason of importing cucumber is to run tests with CI. But recently I've got a problem.

When I deployed to heroku and tried to run `heroku run rake assets:precompile`, I've got:

```
rake aborted!
no such file to load -- cucumber
```

As far as I understand, it can't find the *cucumber* that's only available in test env.

How can I tell rake, to use cure only in test env?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need to wrap it in something like;

```
if Rails.env.test? 
  require 'cucumber'
  require "cucumber/rake/task"
end
```